# Duplicates in javascript fix

Tags: javascript, node.js

In an arrangement I am adding the id that is currently in the for cycle, going through a query, but I do not want duplicate values ​​to be added, as I can know that an id has already been added to the array in order to put a conditional and not add it, or what is the best way to do it

```js
let values = []
values.push({
    "id": id
});
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please provide more detailed example?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: also, a for cycle was mentioned; could you add it to your snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check existing value by using `find` method in array, and then push the value if it does not exist

```js
let values = []

function pushId(id) {
  if (!values.find(value => value.id === id)) {
    values.push({
      id: id
    })
  }
}

pushId(1);
pushId(1);
pushId(2);

console.log(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is very off topic, I will still give you an answer:

All you have to do before adding the ID to the array is to check if the array includes it, like this:

```
let ids = ["123", "321", "123"];
let values = [];
for (id : ids) {
    if (values.includes(id) == false) {
        values.push(id);
    }
}
// values will be ["123", "321"]
```

Your question is off topic because this is something which can easily be solved by a quick google search, and is not really a coding problem that you need help with.